# Data binding adapter. How to get view by id reference?

Tags: android, xml, mvvm, data-binding, android-binding-adapter

I want to specify view reference as atribute to `ImageView`

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"imageUrl", "progressView"}, requireAll = false)
public static void setImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String url, @IdRes int progressBar) {
    Context context = imageView.getContext();
    View progressView  = imageView.getRootView().findViewById(progressBar);
     progressView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

    Glide.with(context).load(url).listener(new RequestListener<String, GlideDrawable>() {
        @Override
        public boolean onException(Exception e, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFirstResource) {
            if (progressView!= null) {
                 progressView.setVisibility.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return false;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onResourceReady(GlideDrawable resource, String model, Target<GlideDrawable> target, boolean isFromMemoryCache, boolean isFirstResource) {
            if (progressView!= null) {
                 progressView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }
            return false;
        }
    }).crossFade().into(imageView);
}
```

however my progress view is null.
I tried cast context to activity and `findViewById` also null
Another solution is just add progress view below Image and when it loads successfully it should be overlayed bt image

Answer (score 13):

Strange that you're seeing a null progressView. You may not have it in your layout maybe?

In any case, you can do this instead:

```
<ProgressBar android:id="@+id/progressBarView" .../>
<!-- other stuff -->
<ImageView app:progressView="@{progressBarView}" app:imageUrl="..." .../>
```

And in your BindingAdapter:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"imageUrl", "progressView"}, requireAll = false)
public static void setImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String url, ProgressBar progressBar) {
    ...
}
```

Comment: This is a great answer. I did have an issue with using progress_bar_view for the id and trying to put that into the app:progressView, but when databinding occurs, id's turn into camelcase.

Answer (score 0):

@BindingAdapter "value" is a array of Strings, so try this:

```
@BindingAdapter(value = {"imageUrl", "progressViewId"}, requireAll = false)
public static void setImageUrl(ImageView imageView, String iamgeUrl, String progressViewStrId) {
     int progressBarId = Integer.valueOf(progressViewStrId);
     ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In my example I pass a ScrollView id as parameter for the BindingAdapter.

This is the layout code:

```
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    app:fadeVisible="@{viewModel.shippingMethodsVisible}"
    app:fadeScrollView="@{scrollView}">
```

And this is the Bindig Adapters code written in Kotlin:

```
@JvmStatic @BindingAdapter(value = ["fadeVisible", "fadeScrollView"], requireAll = false)
fun setFadeVisible(view: View, visible: Boolean, scrollView: ScrollView) {
...
```